# Bug chrome : parent fixed scroll, 1st fixed child (background-color) scrolls too

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an issue in chrome 44 for this code (here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o6b8rdh8/):

```
<div id="body">

    <div id="header">
        Header...
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="main">
            <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="background">

            </div>
            <div id="card">
                Lorem...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

#body {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#background {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

#card {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 50px 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2000px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

[image: Here]

The above is a screenshot of the issue.

The issue is that when I scroll, the fixed background scrolls too. It should stay fixed.

It works perfectly in Firefox 39 and Safari 8.

Any idea how we could fix this?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**:
Same issue on mobile devices. Replicated on OnePlus One and Nexus 9 with both Chrome Latest.

**Edit 2**:
I have updated the fiddle to reflect more the reality. This breaks the answer by @vivekkupadhyay :( .

Here another fiddle that shows the use case when the modal view is closed : http://jsfiddle.net/et0d4dox/1/

The initial fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/o6b8rdh8/) is the use case when the modal is opened.

Comment: It works the same for me in Chrome and Firefox (both latest).

Comment: So the blue background doesn't scroll for you?

Comment: Chrome 44, works! Maybe you have an extension that .... it up?

Comment: Nopes... It doesn't scroll.

Comment: Disable your extensions and recheck!

Comment: Insane, without extensions it still doesn't work. [Cf.](http://imgur.com/AardplS)

Comment: What do you mean by saying "fixed background"?

Comment: #background has a fixed position.

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot of the issue for more visibility..

Comment: I had the same issue on mobile (tested on OnePlus One and Nexus (both with latest Chrome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allright! I found the answer!

We need to add to the `CSS` of `#background` : `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`

`#background` css is now:

```
#background {
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

The updated fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/o6b8rdh8/1/

I am not sure why I need to add this property. If someone has an answer for that, I'll be glad to know.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right about your conditions, then try changing your `CSS` for `#content` like:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;  
    height: calc(100%);
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

it'll definitely do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, it seems to work on the fiddle but not in my real case. I am trying to update the fiddle to reflect "more" my real world case.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to your problem, in a question of my own:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476932/chrome-v45-rendering-absolute-div-background-color-with-scroll

It just seems very related, and the answer with webkit-transform solved our problem too.

It's just that we're also not sure why.

I also referenced this issue in Chrome, which might be relevant:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473020

Thanks :)